# Inserting values in SQL server with a +1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem with some db update scripts that should be run when upgrading out application at the customers site. 
The sql script inserts a lot of new reference data. The primary key is a bigint which is assigned from the application. In the update script, I am fetching the highest existing ID and add one; thus, my inserts look like

```
INSERT INTO RefData (ID, ...) VALUES
  ((SELECT TOP(1) ID + 1 FROM RefData ORDER BY ID DESC), ...),
  ((SELECT TOP(1) ID + 1 FROM RefData ORDER BY ID DESC), ...)
GO
```

This works normally (our server, other customer, ...). But at a specific site, the server tries to insert all rows with the same ID, which fails. It seems to be some parallelism issue; but I don't know how to get rid of this situation.
The update script is too big to rework it in a reasonably amount of time; runtime is not a problem since this is a one-time script.
My questions are:
Is this a parallelism issue? I tried to configure processor affinity to only one cpu, without success.
I also tried to append

OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

also without success.
Does anybody have an idea how to circumvent this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why don't you use select MAX(ID) + 1 FROM RefData? You could also declare the previous max(ID) as a variable, and add a ROW_NUMBER to the others for the insert.

Comment: Does the Cost Threshold for Parallelism match between the servers?  Perhaps it's higher on server were this problem does not exist and is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how your statement would work...

This statement:

```
INSERT INTO RefData (ID, ...) VALUES
  ((SELECT TOP(1) ID + 1 FROM RefData ORDER BY ID DESC), ...),
  ((SELECT TOP(1) ID + 1 FROM RefData ORDER BY ID DESC), ...)
GO
```

Is the same as:

```
DECLARE @Id As BIGINT
SELECT @Id = TOP(1) ID + 1 FROM RefData ORDER BY ID DESC

INSERT INTO RefData (ID, ...) VALUES
  ((SELECT @Id), ...),
  ((SELECT @Id), ...)
GO
```

Comment: I see your point, but at our own sql server instance it works as it should (each row gets its own id). It is only one sql server of 5 which has this problem.

Comment: My point is that in between each select TOP(1), there must be an insert (so that each select gets a new ID). But you're doing two selects on one insert(?)